# Yii2 advance replace url backend/web to admin

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In the yii2 advanced application, need to show admin instead of backend/web and default route to this admin url.

`http://localhost/yapp/backend/web/site/index` to `http://localhost/yapp/admin/site/index` and when running application it should redirect to `http://localhost/yapp/admin`

Comment: You can find the answer into the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls) or searching on SO.

Comment: Look at here https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx

Answer (score 0):

From Yii wiki https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx
to achieve `/admin` in your url.

```
// backend/config.php
components' => [
    ....
    'request'=>[
        ....
        'baseUrl'=>'/admin',
    ],
    ....
],
```

and apache rewrite rule

```
# .htaccess
# Handle the case of admin, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]
```